# Rshiny Ignore download if object not present

Tags: r, shiny, officer

I have a shiny app where users upload 5 data sources, some summary tables are generated, then these tables download to ppt. At present, this download only works if all 5 sources are loaded into the app. I'm trying to find a workaround to this via the "exists" function.

Below is sample code with only one file, demo should work for any csv file.

in the download handler section, the code checks that the dataframe exists through `if (exists("file1.df"))` and will then generate the flextable. The code chunk generating the slide also uses `if (exists("flextable_file1"))`

However the ppt is only still only generating if a file is uploaded. Why aren't sections of the code ignored if the "exists" object doesn't exist?

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
library(officer)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Side bar layout and inputs ----
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      h4("Attach file"),
      fileInput("file1", "File location", accept = c(".csv")),

      downloadButton("download_powerpoint", "Download Tables to Powerpoint")
    ),

    mainPanel(tableOutput("file1.df"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # LMS Pivot ----
  file1.df <- reactive({

    req(input$file1)

    read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
  })

  output$file1.df <- renderTable({
    file1.df()
  })   

  # PPT ----

  output$download_powerpoint <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {  
      "test.pptx"
    },
    content = function(file) {

      if (exists("file1.df")) { 

        flextable_file1 <- flextable(file1.df()) %>% 
          border_remove() %>% 
          border(border.top = fp_border(color = "black"),
                 border.bottom = fp_border(color = "black"),
                 border.left = fp_border(color = "black"),
                 border.right = fp_border(color = "black"), part = "all") %>% 
          align(align = "center", part = "all")
      }

      example_pp <- read_pptx() %>% 
        add_slide(layout = "Title Slide", master = "Office Theme") %>% 
        ph_with_text(
          type = "ctrTitle",
          str = "Weekly P3 Deck"
        ) %>% 
        ph_with(
          location = ph_location_type(type = "subTitle"),
          value = "Copy and paste the generated tables into your report"
        ) 

      # LMS slide ----
      if (exists("flextable_file1")) { 

        example_pp <- example_pp %>% add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>% 
          ph_with_text(
            type = "title",
            str = "words"
          ) %>% 
          ph_with_flextable(
            value = flextable_file1,
            type = "body"
          ) 
      }

      print(example_pp, target = file)
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `file1.df` always exists, even if no file is uploaded. This is a reactive function.

Comment: So what's my work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Rather than using `if exists` use an `if else` to return null if it's not uploaded else return the df.

```
if (is.null(input$file1)) {

        NULL

      } else {

flextable_file1 <- flextableformatting
```

Comment: It is unclear whether this is a comment or an answer to your own question. If this is a comment or extension, use the "edit" button below your question to edit your question and add the new information while giving information using descriptive text. If this is an answer, please add an explanation as to why this provides an answer to your question and mark it as answered, in order to help others with similar problems in the future.